# How to upload RTF file In Ui text view in swift code

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitextview, rtf

How can I load an RTF file in a UITextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you include a file in your app called `rtfdoc.rtf` this will get you started:

```
let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rtfdoc", withExtension: "rtf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width-40,self.view.frame.size.height-40))

textView.attributedText = attributedString

self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

**Edit: Storyboard Version**

Full code as requested. This assumes you have wired up an outlet from the storyboard.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let rtf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rtfdoc", withExtension: "rtf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil) {

            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(fileURL: rtf, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
            textView.attributedText = attributedString
            textView.editable = false
        }


    }

}
```

Note: text is not editable but it remains selectable.

Comment: Thanks A lot, i was looking for this code many days. you are perfect. just one question, when i write this code it shows full page the RTF file text in my App. i want it to be half page. my UI TextView is half page with constraints. do you have any idea? i hope i explained well :)

Comment: sorry how can i do in the way to be NON ediable ?

Comment: You only need an outlet if you are connecting text view from storyboard etc. This is a programmatic approach. To make non-editable set editable property to false.

Comment: Remove let textView line and self.view.addSubview() line. Replace textView with your outlet name

Comment: can you write the sample code of  
Remove let textView line and self.view.addSubview() line. Replace textView with your outlet name –  i tried but it gives Error. Really Thanks..

Comment: Congrats. I was just writing the code out before you added the comment, so thought I'd post it anyway. See above.

Comment: @RobertaJohnson I'd be grateful if you could mark this as the answer if it has worked. Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, can you tell how can i do that:)

Comment: Click on the tick beneath the upvoter/downvoter on the left side of the answer. Might only appear when you hover (I've not asked a question for a while).

Answer (score 3):

with iOS9 the above `NSAttributed` String will give error. You can try the below code for the same:

```
do{
    let attrString =
    try NSMutableAttributedString(URL: rtfPath, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
                textView.attributedText = attrString 
}catch{}
```